# minimum order item for certain products exempting 2 other products (in bulk)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a client that sells books and all their books (except for 2 products, the show special) can be purchased in assorted lots of 12 only.
I have gotten a script that allows me state that 12 lots is required but I need to exclude the 2 specials products from the rule.

Here is the script

```
// Set a minimum number of products requirement before checking out
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_num_products' );
function spyr_set_min_num_products() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Set the minimum number of products before checking out
        $minimum_num_products = 12;
        // Get the Cart's total number of products
        $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;

        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total number of products
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines of
        // A Minimum of 20 products is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
        // Current number of items in the cart: 6   
        if( $cart_num_products < $minimum_num_products ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required before checking out.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                $minimum_num_products,
                $cart_num_products ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

I will be most grateful to have this sorted by able developers here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need some clarifications. What should happens if cart contains a special product and less than 12 regular products (lets say 1 and 11)? Should that special product considered as twelfth product or not?

Comment: @IvanShatsky, thank you for replying. I just want to be able to checkout the special products without the compulsory of 12 products per cart.

Comment: So if the cart contains at least one of the special products it doen't matter how many regular products (if any) are in the cart? Lets say 1 special and 0 regular, 1 special and 1 regular, and so on, the user still should be able to checkout. Am I understand correctly?

Comment: And one more question - how those special products should be identified? Would it be acceptible to you to have a line like `$special_products = array( <id1>, <id2>, ... );` within your function so product identification will occur by the hardcoded list of their IDs?

Comment: One of the other options is to define some custom shipping class and assign that class to those special products. That way you'll be able to manage those products via admin interface without the need to alter PHP code if you would need to make some changes to those rules.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, Would it be acceptable to you to have a line like $special_products = array( <id1>, <id2>, ... ); within your function so product identification will occur by the hardcoded list of their IDs? Yes, this is will work. Thank you

Comment: Regular products have to be 12 before you can checkout. The special products will be alone product in the cart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113923/discussion-between-adeola-adeoti-and-ivan-shatsky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (replace `$special_products = array( <id1>, <id2>, ... );` with your list of product IDs):

```php
// Set a minimum number of products requirement before checking out
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_num_products' );
function spyr_set_min_num_products() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

        // List of "special" products IDs
        $special_products = array( <id1>, <id2>, ... );

        // Get an array of product IDs
        $products = array_column( WC()->cart->get_cart(), 'product_id' );
        if ( $products ) {
            foreach ( $products as $product ) {
                // Return immediately if a "special" product ID found
                // (therefore skipping product count check)
                if ( in_array( $product, $special_products ) ) return;
            }
        }

        // Set the minimum number of products before checking out
        $minimum_num_products = 12;
        // Get the Cart's total number of products
        $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total number of products
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines of
        // A Minimum of 20 products is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
        // Current number of items in the cart: 6   
        if( $cart_num_products < $minimum_num_products ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required before checking out.</strong>' 
                . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                $minimum_num_products,
                $cart_num_products ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

I replace `$cart_num_products = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;` with `$cart_num_products = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();` because the first form is deprecated since WooCommerce 3.0. `global $woocommerce;` is also not needed anymore, nowadays any access to global `$woocommerce` object should be done via `WC()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much but It says there is "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Cart::get_the_cart()" on this line: $products = array_column( WC()->cart->get_the_cart(), 'product_id' );

Comment: @AdeolaAdeoti Sorry, it's my typo, it is `get_cart()`, not `get_the_cart()`. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Do you check it in production? Is it working as expected?

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I need another help with shipping. Do you think you can help? I have 2 flat shipping rates based on location and quantity. For example if 12 products is added to cart, it charges 10 and every increment of 12 will add $10 to it. So if I have 12 products, shipping is 10, 24 is 20, 36 is 30 etc. Special product contains 12 products as well so flat rate is applied accordingly. Do you understand?

Comment: @AdeolaAdeoti Return to the chat room, lets discuss it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113935/discussion-between-adeola-adeoti-and-ivan-shatsky).

Comment: Hello Ivan, I like your help again. Will you be willing to help?

Comment: Sure. What is your question?

Comment: Thank you!, I finally fixed the issue.